# Old Minecraft launcher not working when launching a modpack from twitch

Tags: java, minecraft, twitch

I am trying to run a minecraft modpack from Twitch. The modpack runs in minecraft version 12.2, so it uses the old minecraft launcher. When I try to launch it, the following is displayed in the game output:

'''
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.(Launch.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
'''

I was wondering what the error is and how I could go about fixing it.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? Seems like some other people were having a similar issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/issues/988#issuecomment-573509226).
You could also look at [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/) as a workaround.

Comment: Forge (or launch wrapper) is not compatible with Java 9+. Yes, I have tried to fix it with agents and other hacks.

Answer (score -1):

please try it with another Java Version.
I think the Launcher is to Old for it...